# Trying to open an eclipse project on Android Studio

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

I got a project that was originally made on Eclipse, but I have Android Studio. I tried importing the project to Android Studio and I tried running the application on an emulator and this is the error:

> emulator: ERROR: no search paths found in this AVD's configuration.

Weird, the `AVD's config.ini` file is malformed. Try re-creating it.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, after I imported eclipse project and in the avd manager there were the old images created from eclipse in another sdk folder. 
When I launched the project android studio, it returned this error:

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator. Output: emulator: ERROR: no search
>   paths found in this AVD's configuration. Weird, the AVD's config.ini
>   file is malformed. Try re-creating it.

I resolved the problems quite simply removing all virtual devices and recreating them.